# Using Javascript to check if an HTML snippet is visually empty

Tags: javascript, html

I need to process some HTML snippet embedded as email content, in a node.js server. The goal is to check if the snippet visually appears empty, and if so, display some placeholder text.

For example, this snippet is considered visually empty:

```
<div><br></div><div><includetail><!--<![endif]--></includetail></div>
```

since it will appear empty when rendered in browser, while this snippet is considered visually non-empty:

```
<div><br></div><div>Hello!</div>
```

since `Hello!` will appear when the snippet is rendered in browser.

How to implement such a function to return visual emptiness for an HTML snippet?

Comment: Will you be processing it before you send it in an email? Or when someone opens an email?

Comment: I need to process it from the email content, that is, after the email arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't run `JavaScript` in an email, its really badly supported.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-mail_clients

In general a `jQuery` solution would be something like the following

```
$("*").empty().text("placeholder here");
```

A pure `JavaScript` solution would be

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i].innerHtml === "") {
    list[i].innerHtml = "placeholder here"
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
Since you stated in a comment that you're going to run this in node, have a look at cheerio for a jQuery node replacement. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

My code will work fine after you pass it through cheerio

Comment: I agree @OKsure

Comment: Sorry, I did not state clearly enough -- I need to process email content in a node.js server. So I am not trying to run JS in email. Question updated.

Comment: Updated my answer for node. Let me know if you need any more help @Igc_ustc

Comment: Thanks, @jeanfrg.